# Org mode: refile to other files does not work

Tags: org-mode

I want to be able to refile tasks and todos not only between different headings within a singel org file, but between headings in several org files. To accomplish this I use the following code:

```el
(setq org-refile-targets '(
   (nil :maxlevel . 2)             ; refile to headings in the current buffer
   (org-agenda-files :maxlevel .2) ; refile to any of these files
    ))
```

However, when trying to refile a task with the key  `C-c C-w` I get the following error message:

```
"Wrong type argument: numberp, (0.2)"
```

What is wrong with my code? or is something else lacking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need a space between the `.` and the `2`.

Comment: Thanks ! haha how COULD I overlook that detail : ) Now it works!